# Typescript can't resolve react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, create-react-app

I'm trying to use React Router in Typescript React app. After running `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript`, as told to do in [create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) and installing `@types/react-router-dom` my `package.json` looks as following:

```
{
  "name": "allpic-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My `App.tsx` consists of the following content:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Link to="/">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/upload">
        <h1>Upload</h1>
      </Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <h1>hello world</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Upon running `yarn start` I'm getting these errors:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in '/home/max/Projects/allpic/allpic-frontend/src'
/home/max/Projects/allpic/allpic-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/max/.face.icon'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/max/.face.icon'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

As I said, this is fresh project. I haven't done anything apart from what I mentioned above. I tried to debug this issue by placing a breakpoint at `start.js:19`, but I'm not getting any stack trace from the listener.

How can I overcome this issue and make my Typescript app compile and work with React Router?

Comment: You only installed the react-router-dom type definitions library. You need to install the actual react-router-dom library as well.

Comment: I'm also getting a similar error but unrelated to React. My concern is not missing modules, but instead I'm really concerned about what the hell is looking for `.face.icon` in my home directory and why? I'm also getting ENOENT `/home/user/.steampath`. Anyone got any idea what is looking for these files and why?

Comment: Never mind, it's part of how node resolves modules. Both paths I mentioned area broken symlinks and that's why they're getting reported. There are numerous issues about it, found by searching for `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ".steampath"` for example https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the actual `react-router-dom` library as well.

`yarn add react-router-dom`